# Remove unwanted characters from char type

Tags: esp8266, string, json

I'm working on an ESP8266 module that needs to fetch date data from [worldtimeapi](http://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/Region/City), everything works fine but the problem is **How do I strip of the time field off the datetime JSON response without loop**.

**Note:** Arduino JSON library was used in deserializing the response data and it seems the library only supports `char` data type.

```c++
void loop ()
{
  // Initialize the request object
  HTTPClient request;
  
// Make a http request
  request.begin(dateTime);
  delay(2000);

  // Check the request status code.
int  responseCode = request.GET(); //Get the api host response code.
  Serial.print("Response code is: ");
  Serial.println(responseCode);
  if (responseCode == 200); // If the server returned OK
  {
      String responseData = request.getString();
      Serial.println("Response from the server is:");
      Serial.println(responseData);
        // Deserialize the JSON response data
       StaticJsonDocument<715> result; // Declare data storage to stack
      
      //Check for error during data deserialization
      DeserializationError error = deserializeJson(result, responseData);
      
      if (error) 
      {
        Serial.print(F("Response deserialization failed with reason: "));
        Serial.println(error.f_str());
        return;
      }

      else
      {
        char abbreviation = result["abbreviation"];  // Returns the current time zone abbreviation
        char timezone = result["timezone"]; // Returns the current time zone 
        char datetime = result["datetime"]; // "2021-03-12T17:04:0
        char date = datetime.remove(9,22); // This line throws error : request for member 'remove' in 'datetime', which is of non-class type 'char'

          
        
        Serial.print("Current time is ");
        Serial.print(datetime);
        Serial.print(" ");
        Serial.print(abbreviation);
        Serial.print(" "); 
        Serial.println(timezone);
        delay(2000);
      }
      
  }


}
```

Comment: why `without loop`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `strtok` to split the string on the T character:

```cpp
char *datepart = strtok(datetime, "T");
char *timepart = strtok(NULL, "T");

Serial.print("The current date is: ");
Serial.println(datepart);
Serial.print("The current time is: ");
Serial.println(timepart);
```

An alternative is to just find the `T` and turn it into the NULL terminating character:

```cpp
char *T = strchr(datetime, 'T');
*T = 0;
```

---

If you need to copy the string data into a temporary string first you can do:

```cpp
char temp[strlen(datetime)+1];
strcpy(temp, datetime);
```

Then operate on `temp` instead of `datetime`.

Comment: I need to get rid of **T17:04:0**.

Comment: Then just use `datepart`.

Comment: How do I do that in C++, I think `datepart` is a SQL syntax.

Comment: I have shown you how to do it.

Comment: Followed the ALT but seems the the Arduino Json library has some `const` definition. New error message: `path/to/arduino/libraries/ArduinoJson/src/ArduinoJson/Variant/VariantAs.hpp:94:27: error: invalid conversion from 'ArduinoJson6172_91::enable_if<true, const char*>::type {aka const char*}' to 'char*' [-fpermissive]
   return variantAs<T>(data);`

Comment: You may need to copy the string content to a temporary work string first then.

Comment: Seems to work but the Arduino Json library won't allow that, I'll use NTP Client lib to get the date data. Thank You Majenko.

Comment: What @Majenko suggested works just fine. Define an appropriate sized character array (with an extra for the null terminator) and just `strncpy()` to it.

Comment: @Ruby, esp8266 has built in NTP